# How to debug Repository.fetch_changesets runned from ./script/rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby, redmine, debugging

For some time I have been updating changesets manually on server with following command's:

```
$ cd /custom/www-data/
$ source /custom/www-data/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ ./script/rails runner "Repository.fetch_changesets" -e production
fatal: bad object beacccb6c1107dfd0c62e4dd5d7ffbded9a93af5
```

I suspect that it is some git commit.

I try to find this uuid in repos folder with recursive grep:

grep -rl 'beacccb6c1107dfd0c62e4dd5d7ffbded9a93af5' /data/repos

In repositories folder, but it was not successful.

How to debug Repository.fetch_changesets runned from ./script/rails runner ?

I use redmine-2.3.4 with ruby 2.0.0-p247.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.redmine.org/issues/12505

You can find out which repository contained this `bad object`with following command:

```
$ mysql redmine

mysql> select * from repositories where extra_info like '%beacccb6c1107dfd0c62e4dd5d7ffbded9a93af5%'\G
```

Now you can drop and re-add this repository and everything should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in source:

```
# Redmine is able to be clever and only fetch changesets
# going forward from the most recent one it knows about.
```

If we use mercurial, redmine detect heads automated.
If we use git, we must specify which head we want to use.

To change head in repos table I used following SQL:

```
UPDATE redmine.repositories SET extra_info="---
heads:
- 42ab65e323d6bcc7dbec14f0fa45d220ef5db501
db_consistent:
ordering: 1" 
WHERE id=116;
```